# Get Build Version in automated build deployment using TFS

Tags: deployment, tfs, continuous-integration, build-automation

I am deploying web application to azure using TFS CI automated build deployment.

In our config maintain build version like **2014.05.19.1** which is $(Date).$(rev) format.

All I want to update config each time build is deployed.For that I am passing value to 'BuildVersion' parameter in template to powershell script which actually performs publishing to azure.

I tried using `$(Date:yyyyMMdd)$(Rev:.r)` but it is considered string as it is.

 I want to get current build version just like [IBuildDetail.BuildNumber](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.build.client.ibuilddetail.buildnumber.aspx)
within template.

My question is how to get the build version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Invoke Process, instead of passing value for BuildVersion parameter you can directly use '[BuildDetail.BuildNumber](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.build.server.builddetail.buildnumber.aspx)' in parameters for process like 

`String.Format("-BuildNumber ""{0}""",BuildDetail.BuildNumber)`

This would give the required build number.

Answer (score 1):

If your PowerShell script is being executed from your TFS build, it *should* have access to the environment variables specific to the TFS context of the build. If that is the case, you actually don't need to pass the `$(BuildVersion)` parameter to the script, as it already is accessible to the PS script in the `$env:TF_BUILD_BUILDNUMBER` environment variable. Try testing something like `$env:TF_BUILD_BUILDNUMBER | Out-File "D:\Dev\BuildNumber.txt"` in your script. You should hopefully see the file containing your build number after running your build.

(I am assuming you are using a relatively new build process template...one that contains the "Post-Build script path" parameter, such as TfvcTemplate.12.xaml)

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: I would have to agree with MrHinsh on this. There are ways to hack the build system for deployment, but not without some headaches along the way. We are beginning to implement Release Management now as well and it is definitely the right tool for this.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you use the right tool for the right job. The build system, is really only for building (compile & test). We have been using it for other things for years coz we did not have another integrated solution. However Microsoft recently bought InRelease and rebranded as [Release Management for Visual Studio 2013](http://nakedalm.com/installing-release-management-server-tfs-2013/). I have successfully integrated this with TFS 2012 as well.